# Type Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.PasswordHasher is not defined

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, asp.net-identity

Trying to instantiate instance of Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.PasswordHasher() and getting the error:

Type Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.PasswordHasher is not defined.

Sample VB code was being used:

```
Dim hasher As New Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.PasswordHasher()
```

Answer (score 0):

NuGet package was added to the project to clear up this error message.

Package: Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core

1. Navigate to: Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Manage NuGet Packages for Solution...
2. Click on "Browse" tab
3. Search for Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core
4. In the right side panel check off your project and click install.

Hope this helps someone.